# Remove Html tag when flow create an item in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

My Scenario, i have created a flow that has an action that create a new SharePoint Item,but i found that the content written in the list is surrounded by lots of html tags.I try playing with the column type but didnt help,is there a way to remove those tags?

Comment: any chance you could show us a screen dump of your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ali Jafer i solved it,i was reading a mail and writing the mail body to a sharepoint list.I added an action in the flow that convert html to plain text.